# Latex beamer - showing a slide A with 3 points - then a picture on Slide B - and afterwards slide A with one additional point

Tags: beamer

I want to show a slide that has an overall of 4 items, but I first want to show the first 3 points, all at once, then show a picture that illustrates those 3 points and than show the slide with all 4 items. I think this should somehow work with againframe, but I can't get it to work. So as an example

SlideA:

- Poing1
- Point2
- Point3

SlideB:
Show picture

SlideC:

- Point1 (from slideA)
- Point2 (from slideA)
- Point3 (from slideA)
- Point4 (new)

So long I got this far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame<1-2>[label=framelabel]{
  \frametitle{First Headline}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1> Good point1
    \item<2> Good point2
    \item<2> Good point3
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Good subpoint1
        \item Good subpoint2
      \end{itemize}
    \item<3> Good point4
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{images/ClarinD-Logo}
\end{frame}

\againframe{framelabel2}

\end{document}
```

This unfortunately results in one slide with one point, than another slide with the two points and the subpoints, then there comes the picture and than it starts over again with showing a slide with one item, than another slide with the items marked with<2> and than a slide with the 4th item.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are two possible ways to achieve your goal:

1. **With a single slide, using  `\only`**

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \only<1,3>{
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Point1
   \item Point2
   \item Point3
   \item<3> Point4
   \end{itemize}}
   \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   Like this, the enumeration is shown in overlays 1 and 3, while the image is only shown in frame 2. The fourth `\item` is marked with `<3>` so that it is only visible in this overlay, while the others are shown from the beginning. Using `\only`, the material which doesn't show up at the moment doesn't occupy any space.
2. **With several slides, using `\againframe`**

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}<1>[label=framelabel]
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Point1
   \item Point2
   \item Point3 \pause
   \item Point4
   \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
   \end{frame}

   \againframe<2>{framelabel}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The trick is to create the whole enumeration in one slide, but to show only the first frame/overlay at first (that's what the `<1>` in line 3 does). With the `label` parameter, you give this slide a name so that it can be continued later in your presentation. Then you create the second slide with your image, and resume the first slide afterwards using `\againframe<2>{framelabel}`: This shows the first slide starting with overlay 2 (which wasn't shown when the slide appeared first), so the first points of the enumeration are already there.

Answer (score 6):

How about something simple like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}  

\frame{
\frametitle{testing}
 \only<2>{\begin{center}\huge picture here\end{center}}
 \only<1,3>{
 \begin{itemize}
    \item<1,3> Good point1
    \item<1,3> Good point2
    \item<1,3> Good point3
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Good subpoint1
        \item Good subpoint2
      \end{itemize}
    \item<3> Good point4
  \end{itemize}  
}}

\end{document}
```

The `\only` around the itemize part is necessary in this method to get the vertical centering of the picture right, assuming that's important.

A disadvantage is that if you ever generate a handout from this kind of technique, you have to manually add the handout overlay numbers so that the handout gets the picture too.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand exactly what you mean something in my test case is missing, but your answer is exactly what I need. Many thanks (can't up vote yet).

Comment: @Exocom just that when compiled the point 4 never shows up, and there's no placeholder for the image.  But I guess you just meant that you hadn't figured it out yet (I'll edit my answer to remove that, it should have been a comment anyways).

Comment: You are right, I forgot some lines in the example, I added them now.